# Issue compiling vue files with laravel-mix - broken app.js file

Tags: javascript, laravel, npm, webpack, vue.js

Hi there,

I'm trying to build a web app using the laravel framework. I am using vue components for some of the pages. The current app.js file is working. However, when I run 'npm run watch', 'npm run prod', etc - the components do not show up on any of the pages with vue components. There isn't any errors that occur either. I've tried clearing everything and running 'npm install' and it still happens. It appears that the new app.js file doesn't work. It's happening on both my local environment and the dev server as well.

- npm: 5.6.0
- node: 9.2.1
- laravel-mix: 1.4.2

package.json file:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "gsap": "^1.20.2",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "generate": "^0.14.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "lib": "^3.0.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "package": "^1.0.1",
    "vue-ckeditor2": "^1.15.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.3.4",
    "vue-stripe": "^0.1.3",
    "vue2-timepicker": "^0.1.4",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^0.9.18",
    "vuex": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

webpack.mix.js file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
           alias: {
               "TweenLite": "gsap/src/uncompressed/TweenLite"
           }
        },
        module: {
            rules: [{
                test: require.resolve('jquery'),
                use: [{
                    loader: 'expose-loader',
                    options: '$'
                }]
            }]
        }
   });
```

output of 'npm run watch':

```
➜  YJA git:(master) npm run watch
> @ watch /YJA
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

 10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active                                         
Webpack is watching the files…

 95% emitting                                                                           

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 4961ms                                                                                                                                                                1:08:57 PM

                                                                                                    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1  20.1 kB          [emitted]         
fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb    18 kB          [emitted]         
 fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158  23.4 kB          [emitted]         
  fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512  45.4 kB          [emitted]         
  fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760   109 kB          [emitted]         
                                                                                        /assets/js/app.js  1.53 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /assets/js/app
                                                                                             /css/app.css   147 kB       0  [emitted]         /assets/js/app
```

Please let me know if there's any other information I can help provide!

EDIT: 
/resources/assets/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');

// Vue
window.Vue = require('vue');

import axios from 'axios';

import UserAdmin from "./components/user/UserAdmin.vue";

import EventRegistration from "./components/event/EventRegistration.vue";
import NewEvent from "./components/event/event_new/NewEvent.vue";
import EventRegistered from "./components/event/EventRegistered.vue";
import EventStatus from "./components/event/event_update/EventStatus.vue";
import EventFeedback from "./components/event/event_update/EventFeedback.vue";
import EventUpdate from "./components/event/event_update/EventUpdate.vue";
import EventUpdatedAt from "./components/event/event_update/EventUpdatedAt.vue";

import NewAddon from "./components/addon/NewAddon.vue";
import UpdateAddon from "./components/addon/UpdateAddon.vue";

import AdminNotifications from "./components/admin/AdminNotifications.vue";

import AdminTransactions from "./components/admin/AdminTransactions.vue";

Vue.component('Banner', require('./components/Banner.vue'));
Vue.component('appContactForm', require('./components/ContactForm.vue'));
Vue.component('appSocial', require('./components/Social.vue'));
Vue.component('accountDashboard', require('./components/account/AccountDashboard.vue'));

export const userBus = new Vue();
export const stripeBus = new Vue();
export const eventBus = new Vue();

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
        userAdmin: UserAdmin,
        eventRegistration: EventRegistration,
        newEvent: NewEvent,
        eventRegistered: EventRegistered,
        eventUpdatedAt: EventUpdatedAt,
        eventStatus: EventStatus,
        eventFeedback: EventFeedback,
        eventUpdate: EventUpdate,
        newAddon: NewAddon,
        updateAddon: UpdateAddon,
        adminNotifications: AdminNotifications,
        adminTransactions: AdminTransactions
    }
});
```

Comment: code snippet are for working/failing examples. you can just add `code` in your question.

Comment: sorry about that - fixed!

Comment: No errors in console? u have vue devtools?

Comment: I just tried using the chrome extension vue devtools. Prior to running 'npm run watch', the extension recognizes that there is vue.js on the page. However, afterwards it does not. 

I don't see any errors in laravel.log nor the web console.

Comment: And you have <script> at the bottom of your page pointed correctly to app.js?And the correct id(default is #app) for Vue instance?

Comment: yes I believe so.  also not sure why but for the version where the components show, the chrome plugin says "Vue.js is detected on this page. Devtools inspection is not available because it's in production mode or explicitly disabled by the author." -- I changed my app_env to development and enabled the setting in the extension setting. Any idea?

Comment: in chrome console, an error does appear with the broken app.js

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'StripeCheckout' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at t (app.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at t (app.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at t (app.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:1)
    at t (app.js:1)
    at app.js:1
    at app.js:1`

Comment: Edit your post and add the content of `resources/assets/js/app.js`.

Comment: @Konafets - code added!

Comment: A little late but @daviolinist12, it looks like you're missing the `.vue()` call in your **webpack.mix.js** file:
so `mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/assets/js').vue()` should be in there to enable Vue support.